# Mapping an instance of IList in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, mapping

I'm trying to map a parent-child relationship using NHibernate (2.1.2), MySql.Data (6.2.2) and MySQL Server (5.1). I figured out that this must be done using a `<bag>` in the mapping file. I build a test app which is running without yielding any errors and is doing an `insert` for each entry but somehow the foreign key inside the children table (ParentId) is always empty (null).

Here are the important parts of my code...

#### Parent

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}


<class name="Parent">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>        
  <bag name="Children" cascade="all">
    <key column="ParentId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
  </bag>    
</class>
```

#### Child

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

<class name="Child">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>    
</class>
```

#### Program

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{                                
     session.Save(
        new Parent() 
        {
            Children = new List<Child>() 
            { 
                new Child(), 
                new Child() 
            } 
        });
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap all your data access in a transaction. This will work:

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{                                
     session.Save(
        new Parent() 
        {
            Children = new List<Child>() 
            { 
                new Child(), 
                new Child() 
            } 
        });
     tx.Commit();
}
```

In fact, the inserts are only being performed because you're using a `native` generator; with a client-side generator they wouldn't even be sent to the DB.

Comment: I do not need to use a transaction. Its the implicit call of ISession.Flush() from ITransaction.Commit() that made your code work. For more details see: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

Comment: That's true, but you DO need to use transactions. Please read http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
<class name="Child">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>    
  <many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentID"/>
</class>
```

Comment: This wont help me because I want to map a list of child to a parent - not the other way around.

Comment: That's why I have a many-to-one in there.  Child is the many side, Parent is the one side.  In all our mappings, we specify both sides and it works.